# trying to print 'host' of url using php's url_parse function

Tags: php

I want to print all the 'host' keys against a list of urls using url_parse function, but it's not working with this code.

```
   $filename = 'urls.txt';

   $urls = file($filename);



   function printRow($value, $key) {
   $bits = url_parse($value);
   echo $value['host'];
   };

    $host = implode(',', $urls);
    array_walk($host, "printRow");
```

Comment: "getting through" is uninformative.

Comment: you are not using $key anywhere in the function then why do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

if contents of your url.txt is

```
http://exam2.com,http://exam1.com,.......
```

then your script will be

```
$filename = 'urls.txt';

$urls = file_get_contents($filename);



function printRow($value) {
$bits = url_parse($value);
return  $bits;
};

$host = explode(',', $urls);
$i=0;
foreach ($host as $hosts)
{
$dom=printRow($hosts);
$all_arr[$i]=$dom['host'];
$i++;
}
print_r ($all_arr);
```